# How to remove duplicate nodes based on their children?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-2.0

Suppose I have the following sequence:

```
<node-1> <children-A attr="100" /> </node-1>
<node-1> <children-A attr="200" /> </node-1>     <!--not a duplicate -->
<node-1> <children-B /> </node-1>
<node-1> <children-B /> </node-1>                <!-- duplicate off the above -->
<node-1> <children-A /> <children-B /> </node-1> <!--not a duplicate -->
```

I want to obtain all unique "node-1" so that the output would be:

```
<node-1> <children-A attr="100" /> </node-1>
<node-1> <children-A attr="200" /> </node-1>
<node-1> <children-B /> </node-1>
<node-1> <children-A /> <children-B /> </node-1>
```

NOTE: only `<node-1> <children-B /> </node-1>` has been removed.

Using Saxon 9.1.0.8, I've tried `distinct-value($S)` but the return type is `xs:anyAtomicType` and I don't know how to cast it to a proper sequence (if that's even possible!).

I am, however, able to use `count(distinct-value($S))` to check if the number of elements returned match the actual number of unique elements, and in fact it does match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_distinct-deep.html (which in turn uses http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal.html which in turn uses the XSLT/XPath 2.0 function `deep-equal`) you could use `<xsl:variable name="distinct-seq" select="functx:distinct-deep($your-sequence)"/>`.

Or if you don't want or can't include the functx library you would need to use its code in

```
<xsl:variable name="distinct-seq"
  select="for $pos in (1 to count($your-sequence))
          return $your-sequence[$pos]
                               [not(some $node in $your-sequence[position() lt $pos] satisfies deep-equal(., $node))]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is actually an XPath 2.0 question.**

**Use**:

```
   for $vN in /*/*
     return
        $vN[not(/*/*[. >> $vN and deep-equal(., $vN)])]
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "for $vN in /*/*
     return
        $vN[not(/*/*[. >> $vN and deep-equal(., $vN)])]

  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided fragment wrapped into a single top element):

```
<t>
 <node-1> <children-A attr="100" /> </node-1>
 <node-1> <children-A attr="200" /> </node-1> 
 <node-1> <children-B /> </node-1>
 <node-1> <children-B /> </node-1> 
 <node-1> <children-A /> <children-B /> </node-1> 
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<node-1>
   <children-A attr="100"/>
</node-1>
<node-1>
   <children-A attr="200"/>
</node-1>
<node-1>
   <children-B/>
</node-1>
<node-1>
   <children-A/>
   <children-B/>
</node-1>
```